# Make dropdown multi-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 dropdowns and one of them(the second one) is dynamic in the sense that its values change according to the option chosen in the first dropdown.

JSFiddle result: http://jsfiddle.net/pgbw56vb/10/embedded/result/

Can someone pls show me how i can make the second dropdown a multi-select? I'm really green in Jquery and html.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pgbw56vb/10/

```
 <select id="kategorie_oder_seite"></select>

 <select id="auswahl"></select>

 var data = {
 "Kategorie": ["Kraft", "Startseite", "Insurance", "Risk",],
 "Seite": ["http://jsfiddle.net/tony089/pgbw56vb/2/",     "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2fask"],
 };


 var $kategorien = $("#kategorie_oder_seite").on("change", function() {
 var seiten = $.map(data[this.value], function(seite) {
    return $("<option />").text(seite);
 });
 $("#auswahl").empty().append(seiten);
 });

 for (var kategorie in data) {
 $("<option />").text(kategorie).appendTo($kategorien);
 }

 $kategorien.change();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add the `multiple` attribute to the select.

Comment: `<select id="auswahl" multiple></select>`

Comment: to select multiple items do this `<select id="auswahl" multiple></select>`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have tried adding the multiple attribute and this happens:

JSFiddle result: http://jsfiddle.net/tony089/pgbw56vb/28/embedded/result/

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tony089/pgbw56vb/28/

Its not the result i want.

Comment: Maybe you should tell what kind of behaviour you are expecting instead, and then...

Comment: I would like to be able to select more than one option on a dropdown list.

Comment: @TonyOkoth but that's the purpose of multiple attribute, using Ctrl key.

Comment: Is there any other attribute that would allow me to select more than one item on the list while it still able to expand and contract? (without using ctrl-key)

Comment: @TonyOkoth so when the dropdown should collapse? After how many items selected? You would have better to use a plugin instead...

Comment: @TonyOkoth Try this plugin http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/

Comment: It is counter intuitive to change the behaviour of a select. If you want something selectable that collapses/expands, get a widget

Answer (score 4):

you can use the `multiple` attribute of select tag and set its value to `multiple`. also remember to set the `name` property in array form so that you could send multiple values via this `select` control.

eg.

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="kategorie_oder_seite" name="check[]"></select>
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pgbw56vb/10/

Comment: This is what i get when i add the attributes you suggested. 

JSFiddle result: http://jsfiddle.net/tony089/pgbw56vb/31/embedded/result/

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tony089/pgbw56vb/31/

I would like the dropdown list to be able to expand and contract like a typical dropdown list and allow me to select more than one option.

Answer (score -1):

just add "multiple" attribute on the "select" tag

Answer (score -1):

Add multiple to your select tags.

```
 <select id="kategorie_oder_seite" multiple></select>  
 <select id="auswahl" multiple></select>
```